# JIRA issue navigator due date format

Tags: jira

By default JIRA Issue Navigator displays Due date column value using pattern: `yyyy-MM-dd` or `dd/MM/yy`.

Is it possible to display also hours and minutes?

For example using date format pattern `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm`.

P.S.
[This article](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA051/Showing+Extended+Timestamp+in+the+Created+Column+of+the+Issue+Navigator) shows how to change format of the Created (and also Updated) columns.
Strange, but it doesn't apply to the system Due date column...

Comment: if you need a coding example let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system Due Date field is implemented in DueDateSystemField.java which uses the template
atlassian-jira/WEB-INF/classes/templates/jira/issue/field/duedate-view.vm
to render the view of that field. Unfortunately only the formatted string for the date is passed to the template. You'd also need to change the edit template to use a date time picker though.

My recommendation would be to create your own custom field of type Date Time instead of Date Picker and use that.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I did as you said (created own custom field) and it worked.